# error while running react native app

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

i'm installing react native while running my first app in react native android in windows . i'm getting error

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'. > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. > Could not resolve project :react-native-default-preference. Required by: project :app > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-default-preference: None of the consumable configurations have attributes. in react native

Comment: It means you have not correctly linked `react-native-default-preference` library, follow the steps given in the library to work with it.

Comment: what i have to follow can you please tell me.

Comment: It is given there in [github repo](https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-default-preference#readme), once you follow all the steps make sure to sync your android project and run it.

Comment: i'm working in vs code in react native code where should i add the lib .

Answer (score 0):

You should clear cache and try again

```
RN < 0.50 - watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && 
npm cache clean && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache
RN >= 0.50 -  watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache clean && npm 
install && npm start -- --reset-cache

npm >= 5 - watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && 
npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache

Windows - del %appdata%\Temp\react-native-* & cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & del 
node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & npm install & npm start -- --reset-cache
```

answer is from https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d